# Sorting a list in the buffer?

Tags: sort

Is there a way to sort a list (single column, each item separated by `\r`) in the buffer using just vim?

Comment: @Nobe4, really? `help list-functions`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in sort utility:

```
:sort
```

Or pipe the buffer to an external Unix command:

```
:%!sort
```

For more info and options see `:help :sort` and `man sort`.

Comment: Neat I didn't know you could pipe the contents of a buffer to a command!  Thanks man!

Comment: That's one of Vim's superpowers. If you use it, [Unix is your IDE](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442419-vim-tips-working-with-external-commands).

Comment: `:sort` works on the whole buffer by default so you can leave out the `%`.